# Cannot resolve keyword u'slug' into field error in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am getting the following error:

```
FieldError at /blog/1/first-post/

Cannot resolve keyword u'slug' into field. Choices are: article, date, id, likes

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/1/first-post/
Django Version:     1.6.2
Exception Type:     FieldError
Exception Value:    

Cannot resolve keyword u'slug' into field. Choices are: article, date, id, likes
```

My model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="/", blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug, 'id':self.id})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Detail(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    date = models.DateField()
    likes = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.article.title, self.likes)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail_article', kwargs={'id':self.id})
```

View:

```
class ArticleDetail(DetailView):
     model = Detail
     template_name = "article_detail.html"
     context_object_name = "details"

     def get_queryset(self):
        print self.kwargs['slug']
        a = Article.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        # print Details.object.get()
        # print Detail.objects.filter(article__slug=self.kwargs['slug']) fails with same error
        return Detail.objects.filter(article=a)
```

urls.py (this is inside by blog app):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'all$', ArticleList.as_view(), name='blog_all'),
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
url(r'^detail/?(P<id?\d+)/$', DetailArticle.as_view(), name='detail_article'),
url(r'^create$', ArticleCreateView.as_view(), name='blog_create'),
)
```

Basically the detailView of an `article instance` will display the contents of `detail` model that has foreignkey relationship to `article model`. It is not the traditional way where the detail view of `article` instance displays that instance.

Template here:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for detail in details %}
<p>{{ detail.article.title }}</p>
<p>{{ detail.date }}</p>
<p>{{ detail.likes }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Does field 'slug' exist in your database?

Comment: @zymud: yes it does for the `article` model. I can see it in admin and query in shell

Comment: please show your template

Comment: @zymud: template added above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: you need to rename slug parameter in url to other name, or in your view set slug_url_kwarg some other value - not 'slug'

Explanation:
When you add  to url, django tries to get object by slug and your model Detail has no slug field.

Link to django code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L33

**UPDATE**

in SingleObjectMixin:

```
slug = self.kwargs.get(self.slug_url_kwarg, None)
...
elif slug is not None:
    slug_field = self.get_slug_field()
    queryset = queryset.filter(**{slug_field: slug})
```

so django gets slug from your url, tries to get slug field from Detail model and fails

Your view need to rewrite slug_url_kwarg attribute:

```
class ArticleDetail(DetailView):
    model = Detail
    template_name = "article_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "details"
    slug_url_kwarg = "not_slug" # this attribute

 def get_queryset(self):
    print self.kwargs['slug']
    a = Article.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    # print Details.object.get()
    # print Detail.objects.filter(article__slug=self.kwargs['slug']) fails with same error
    return Detail.objects.filter(article=a)
```

but I think better way is to change  to attribute  in your url:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<article_slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
```

and get article_slug from view kwargs

Comment: can you please elaborate what you mean by 'in your view set slug_url_kwarg some other value - not slug` please give by code example if possible

Answer (score 8):

overriding the `get_object(self, queryset=None)` method instead of DetailView `get_queryset(self)` is an easier solution

```
class ArticleDetail(DetailView):
    model = Detail
    template_name = "article_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "details"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        a_obj = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)
        try:
           d_obj = Detail.objects.get(article=a_obj)
        except Detail.DoesNotExist:
            d_obj = None
        except Detail.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            #select the apt object
        return d_obj
```

Comment: You need to set `d_obj=None` and you need to put a tab on `return d_obj`